# Windows clients slow to open SAMBA on Debian 10 (when using short hostname)

Tags: debian, samba, smb

I'm having a strange problem for windows 8 and 2012R2 clients, which use a Debian 10 samba server in ADS mode. The issue is slow initial directory listing of the server, only when using the server's short name i.e. "\server"

If clients use \server.mydomain.example or \Server_IP_Address connections are very fast. If they use \server the connection takes between 1 and 30 seconds to show the initial directory listing.

I confirm that short name resolution works 100%. All windows hosts report IP address on:

```
nbtstat -a server
```

or
ping server

I tried to play some more with smb.conf (this works perfectly on my old Centos 6):

```
netbios name = server
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE
```

With and without these options FQDN and IP connections are lightning fast, while the short "server" name takes some time. Usually clients return:
0x80070035 or 0x80004005

Have anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: I think you are on the wrong site. This site is about programming (and tools for programmers). I think the sister site "server fault" (link on top right icon) is possibly more appropriate (or maybe the Unix&Linux site).

Comment: Thank you! My mistake.